# Hi-Lo guessing game with numbers

Tags: java, number-guessing-game

I am new to Java in general, but wanted to get some input on the code for a CS class I am taking.  It is a program that plays the Hi-Lo guessing game with numbers. A user may choose to quit mid-game by entering 0 and then they are prompted to play again if they choose.  If they guess correctly, they are also prompted to play again.

The code works fine, however, my original direction was to use the `while` loop as the main conditional instead of the `do` statement but I couldn't get the game to start again after the user entered 0 to exit the loop. I'm curious to know how I can use the `while` loop as the main conditional vs the `do` statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int guess, answer, count = 0;
        String restart;

        Random generator = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What number do you guess (enter 0 to quit)? ");
        guess = scan.nextInt();

        answer = generator.nextInt(100) + 1; // randomly generates a number between 1-100

        do // loops through game until user gets answer correct or quits
        {
            count++;

            if (guess == 0) // if user enters 0 to quit game, this message is displayed
            {
                System.out.println("\nQuitting game");
                System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again?");
                restart = scan.next();
                if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter a number to start playing");
                    guess = scan.nextInt();
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (guess == answer)
            {
                System.out.println("That's correct! You made " + count + " guesses.");
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
                restart = scan.next();
                if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter a number to start playing");
                    guess = scan.nextInt();
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (guess < answer)
            {
                System.out.print("Your guess is too low, try again.");
                guess = scan.nextInt();
            }
            if (guess > answer)
            {
                System.out.print("Your guess is too high, try again.");
                guess = scan.nextInt();
            }

        }
        while (guess != 0);

        System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't repeat yourself

You twice say

> ```
>                 System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again?");
>                 restart = scan.next();
>                 if (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
>                 {
>                     System.out.print("Enter a number to start playing");
>                     guess = scan.nextInt();
>                 }
>                 else
>                     break;
> ```

And five times say

> ```
>                     guess = scan.nextInt();
> ```

Including twice in the previous repeated code.  Don't do that.  Instead organize the code so that you say these things once each.

Consider the following

```
        String restart = "Y";
        while (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            int answer = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;

            System.out.print("What number do you guess (enter 0 to quit)? ");
            while (true) {
                int guess = scan.nextInt();
                if (guess == 0) {
                    System.out.println("\nQuitting game");
                    break;
                }

                count++;
                if (guess == answer) {
                    System.out.println("That's correct! You made " + count + " guesses.");
                    break;
                }

                if (guess < answer) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low, try again.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high, try again.");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again (Y/N)?");
            restart = scan.next();
        }
```

This won't necessarily work any better.  But this pattern will generally be easier to maintain.  One of the problems with academic code is its low reuse.  You never have to maintain it, so it's easy to slip into unmaintainable habits.  Outside the academic context, most of your time will be spent on maintaining existing code.

I used a `while` for the outer loop even though a `do`/`while` would have been more natural (since you always loop once).  Notice though that it is gated by `restart` rather than `guess`.  I find this to be a cheesy solution and would prefer the `do`/`while`.

The inner loop will loop forever until explicitly exited (with the `break` statements).  Notice how the first thing that it does is collect the next `guess`.  This saves collecting it in the five different places.  Collect it once and then process it once.

When processing `guess`, you don't need to do three comparisons.  There are only three states.  If it's not equal (otherwise we `break` out of the loop) and not less than, it must be greater than.  So use an `else` rather than the third comparison.

We could also use an `else if` after `guess == answer`, but we don't need to do so since we `break`.

I added a `(Y/N)` to your play again query.  As is, it works if you know how.  But someone who doesn't know what to do might type "Yes." which seems like a reasonable response but won't work.  Give a little extra guidance as to what to type there.  You also might consider accepting "Yes" as a positive answer.

The Java standard is to put `{` on the same line as a method declaration or control structure, so I switched to that.  It's more important to be consist though.  So the other way is OK.  It's just not how I normally write Java.

#### Bugs

You don't manage the `count` correctly.  I fixed a small mistake for you, but I left the bigger one.  The small mistake was that you incremented the `count` even if the `guess` was 0, which is not a real guess but the exit criterion.  Without the larger mistake, this doesn't really matter.  You don't display the incorrect `count` anyway.

The larger mistake comes when you play repeated games.  To my mind, the correct way to fix this would be to move the `count` declaration and initialization to a different location.  Note that in Java, variable declarations do not need to be at the beginning of a block.  They can appear anywhere.  Figure out what's wrong with the current behavior (win repeated games until it becomes obvious).  Then think about where it should be.

#### Use methods

I would prefer to move `generator` and `scan` into class fields.  This means inside the class but outside any method.

```
    private static final Random GENERATOR = new Random();
    private static final Scanner SCAN = new Scanner(System.in);
```

That would allow them to be shared across multiple methods.

I would expect `main` to look more like

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String restart;
        do {
            play();

            System.out.println("Would you like to play again (Y/N)?");
            restart = SCAN.next();
        } while (restart.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
    }
```

Perhaps you haven't gotten to methods yet.  When you do, consider going back to this and writing a `play` method.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Thank you for your feedback.  Very helpful and since I posted this thread, have learned more about using methods and Java in general.  I realize a lot of original code was redundant after reading your post and made the necessary corrections.  How do I go about voting up your answer or can I not do that since I am a new user?

Comment: Also, you mentioned moving constructors into class fields, is this in between the actual class declaration and the main method in my code above?  If yes, is this better in terms of best practices?  All the examples in my class so far have constructors within a main method.  I know real world applications tend to be different then academic settings.

Comment: Yes, if you put the declaration inside the class and outside any method, that works.  The argument against declaring them in `main` is that you only want them to be declared once and that you want them available in all methods.  This is rooted in the specifics of `Random` and `Scanner` and may not apply in other situations.  You need 4 more reputation to upvote.  If you get another upvote on this, another question, or on an answer, you will have enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Indentation**
Your main function needs to be indented one level inside your class.

**Functions**
Your code would benefit by moving some of the code in main() to functions. The main() function should generally be a place to process arguments, initialize the program and catch any exceptions. As it's currently implemented you need another variable to get a while loop to work. If the guessing part was in another function the while loop would be easier to implement.

**Multiple Loops**
You should have one loop for continuing the game, and another loop for the guessing part.